# What is the summary of the Ninth Canto of Devi Bhagavata Purana?

Tags: krishna, radha, devi-bhagavata-purana

Recently, I came across the Devi Bhagavata Purana. In it were many interesting and informative topics. However, I am unable to understand the Ninth Canto of the Purana, owing to fact that I find the English used there too "Shakespearean" for me. I can only understand that there was Krishna at the beginning and he split into Mula Prakriti and himself. Other than that, I am unable to understand the rest of the text there. When I researched about the Ninth canto of this Purana, I only found that it was about Radha.

Can someone summarize the part on Radha, Krishna and the creation of the universe from the Ninth Canto?

Comment: You can read ninth book [here](https://archive.org/details/srimaddevibhagav26vijnuoft) translated by Swami Vijnanananda, if you find that book as difficult.

Comment: @The Destroyer That is the same book I have as well.Could you please read the part on Radha and Krishna and the creation of the universe and summarise it for me?